# Deploy the database to Docker Container microsoft/mssql-server-linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a database running on SQL Server (13.01) on Windows. I like to deploy it to the Docker Container on Linux using SSDT.

I can perfectly connect to the server running on Docker and create/drop database manually and play with the data.

The problem is I can not publish it. I'm executing following script on Powershell

```
PS: SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"d.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"server=containeraddress;database=thedatabase;user id=sa;password=thepassword;
```

and getting the following error.

> Unable to connect to master or target server 'the database'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'the database'. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

I have the same user and same password on target and source servers.

Is there anybody has the same problem and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of SqlPackage.exe are you using? Only the most recent release candidate versions of SqlPackage.exe support SQL Server vNext CTP.  The SqlPackage release candidate can be downloaded here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54273

Answer (score 4):

I'll post this here as most of the answers refer to having an existing compiled dacpac file, which may not always be possible.  I haven't seen similar ideas posted elsewhere to the solution I'm suggesting here.

Given your usage of docker and if you wish to compile your visual studio project inside the container, given certain combinations of the container base OS and image may not be possible to create a dacpac file with msbuild.

You can work around restoring the database using a series of unix based commands, taking note that the visual studio database project is usually just a series of SQL files, below I show an example of this, where I concat the SQL files into a single file and call sqlcmd to run the script;

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
WORKDIR /init
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=MyPassword
EXPOSE 1433:1433
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install dos2unix
COPY /solution_folder/database/Tables/*.sql /init/
WORKDIR /database
RUN echo "CREATE DATABASE [database_name];\nGO\nUSE [database_name];\n” >> /database/create.sql
RUN for f in /init/*.sql; do dos2unix $f;  cat $f >> /database/create.sql; echo "\nGO\n" >> /database/create.sql; done
RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started"  && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ‘MyPassword’ -i /database/create.sql && pkill sqlservr
```

The reason for "dos2unix" is that the SQL files created within visual studio have unique hidden cr/lf (and other characters) which the linux version of sqlcmd won't interpret successfully and will cause errors (which is kind of bizarre and this is exactly the kind of thing you'd want a cross platform database to be able to cope with)

Also, within the final run command you have to start-up the sql server service temporarily otherwise you'll also get errors; it's a little bit of work-around, and a bit fiddly and I'm not sure entirely that the microsoft sql server linux container is well designed enough for the simple task of restoring a database like this, the nuances are the differences between building and running a container and needing some sort of happy middle ground of both concepts for it to work.

Given here isn't a complete solution to restore, it only deals with Tables from the project file, although it should be trivial to expand to scalar functions and stored procedures.